# Ingress not showing up in loadbalancer

Tags: kubernetes, terraform

When examining this particular Terraform configuration, the intended purpose is to declare a load balancer that is appropriately connected to an ingress resource. However, upon closer inspection of the dashboard, it appears that the expected ingress resource is not displaying on the load balancer, which may indicate that the load balancer is not properly configured to communicate with the ingress resource. This may be a result of incorrect settings or misconfigured parameters within the Terraform code. As such, further investigation and refinement of the configuration may be necessary to ensure that the desired functionality is achieved.

```
module "cert_manager" {
  source        = "terraform-iaac/cert-manager/kubernetes"

  cluster_issuer_email                   = "t@gmail.com"
  cluster_issuer_name                    = "cert-manager-global"
  cluster_issuer_private_key_secret_name = "cert-manager-private-key"

  create_namespace = false
  namespace_name = kubernetes_namespace.cmprimg.metadata[0].name
}

resource "kubernetes_ingress_v1" "my-app-ingress" {
  metadata {
    name = "ingress"
    namespace = kubernetes_namespace.cmprimg.metadata[0].name
    annotations = {
      "cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer" = module.cert_manager.cluster_issuer_name
      # "kubernetes.io/ingress.class" = "nginx"
      "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect" = "true"
      # "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough" = "true"
    }
    labels = {
      "service" = "ingress-controller"
    }
  }

  wait_for_load_balancer = true

  spec {
    tls {
      hosts = [ "api.mywebsite.xyz" ]
      secret_name = module.cert_manager.cluster_issuer_private_key_name
    }

    ingress_class_name = "nginx"

    rule {
      host = "api.cmprimg.io"

      http {
        path {
          path = "/loader"
          backend {
            service {
              name = kubernetes_service.httploader_service.metadata[0].name
              port {
                name = kubernetes_service.httploader_service.spec[0].port[0].name
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_service" "ingress_loadbalancer" {
  metadata {
    name      = "ingressservice"
    namespace = kubernetes_namespace.cmprimg.metadata[0].name
    labels = {
      service = "ingress-controller"
    }
  }

  spec {
    type = "LoadBalancer"
    selector = {
      app = "ingress"
    }

    port {
      app_protocol = "both"
      port         = 443
      # target_port  = 443
      name         = kubernetes_service.http_service.spec[0].port[0].name
    }
  }
}
```

[image: k8s dashboard with missing ingress]

I made sure all the labels and selectors are right but I'm new to terraform and kubernetes. Where did I make a mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your load-balancer is configured to pass traffic to pods according to the `selector` within its `spec`:

```
    selector = {
      app = "ingress"
    }
```

Your ingress service doesn't have that within its labels, so it won't be used. To fix, you'll need to update your service to have something like

```
    labels = {
      "service" = "ingress-controller"
      "app" = "ingress"
    }
```

At least that's the first thing I can see - I haven't used k8s for a while, so this might not be everything.